# Symplectic integration for non-separable hamiltonian

Tags: numerical-methods, classical-mechanics, online-resources, hamilton-equations

does anyone have experience with symplectic integrators when applied to non-separable Hamiltonians? More specifically with regard to constructing high order symplectic integrators for non-separable Hamiltonians?

I know there is [Yoshida's article](http://cacs.usc.edu/education/phys516/Yoshida-symplectic-PLA00.pdf) but this is specific to separable Hamiltonians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoshida's trick applies to all symmetric integrators. So if symplectic structure preservation is important to you then using e.g. the implicit midpoint and Yoshida's trick allows you to make arbitrary high order symplectic methods. Do note however, that Yoshida's trick gives terrible error constants and using e.g. high order Gauss methods (also symplectic) gives much better results. Recent results by Murua et al as well as results by Hairer show how fast fixed point iterations can be used to solve the resulting implicit/nonlinear equations when using Gauss methods.

Comment: Can you give references for these results?  I cannot see where this answer deals with the non-separable Hamiltonian aspect.I am attempting to use one of Hairer's methods (equations 3 in https://www.unige.ch/~hairer/poly_geoint/week2.pdf).  However these equations are _not_ symmetrical for non-separable Hamiltonians, so the statement that "Even order 2 follows from its symmetry" does not seem to apply.  This would make an integrator based on equations (3) order 1, and not composable.

Comment: The Yoshida integrator (and by extension Forest-Ruth) is truly _awful_ at larger step sizes (see Hairer), and can produce truly Dali-esque trajectories in those conditions.  I recommend _always_ to use the Suzuki 5-step integrator, it works well at large step-sizes too.