# Composed symplectic integrator for non-separable hamiltonian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, symplectic-geometry

Firstly, I have seen [Symplectic integration for non-separable hamiltonian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140492/symplectic-integration-for-non-separable-hamiltonian), and I do not believe it answers my question.

I have been attempting to modify a symplectic integrator that I wrote a while ago. It works very well for "separable" hamiltonians, but I want to use it to simulate a double pendulum.

I am using the Hamiltonian from (13) in [this source](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=e5ac36fcb129ce95a61f8e8ce0572dbf).

I am using the Stormer-Verlet equation (3) from [this source](https://www.unige.ch/~hairer/poly_geoint/week2.pdf). From the article "Even order 2 follows from its symmetry."

In the case of a separable hamiltonian, ∇q is a function *only* of q, and similarly for p, so that the equations form a symmetrical sequence of three function calls.

For a non-separable hamiltonian, this is no longer true, and it is necessary to use the full equations, but these are no longer symmetrical (the first two are implicit whilst the last is explicit).  In other words, the first and third (q update) equations are *not* the same.

Anyhow, I have implemented the full non symmetrical equations, and while they are "symplectic" in the sense that there is no systematic "energy creep" in the output, they are only first order WRT step size, and my attempts to increase the order via composition are ineffective (the composition is still first order).

So, my question is this: is it possible to compose these implicit equations, or does their asymmetry prevent this? In other words, have I just made an error somewhere in my implementation?

Comment: I am currenty looking at https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02212, which seems to offer a generic and possible very simple solution to non-separable systems (double pendulum, black hole metrics).